# Angular2 text mask add support for text

Tags: javascript, angular, text-mask

How do i add both text and number in my mask

Currently am using

```
[/\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
```

THe above only allows numbers.How do i add allow for text also?

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: yes https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask

Comment: Can you post your component code or fiddle where you using the mask?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if: "\s" is supported by the plugin or you can also use [A-Za-z] at the places you need to allow